# Pi3 "unable to resolve host" message

Tags: raspbian, sudo

I have a message saying:"sudo: unable to resolve host (myhostname)"  each time i write a command.
My hostname do not contain any capital letter or number. 
thank you

Comment: Does `/etc/hosts` contain an entry like `127.0.1.1       myhostname`?

Comment: Thank you, i added myhostname in this file and the message went disappered.

Comment: I have another problem it concerns the Wifi. i can't really connect to my router, i added my connection information in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and changed /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Also, the wifi icon mentions Wlan0 " No wifi interfaces found"

Comment: "changed /etc/network/interfaces" is probably your problem **DO NOT MODIFY** See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
 Also if you changed your hostname using `raspi-config` you would not probably have had the problem you originally posted.

Comment: raspi-config on a fresh Raspbian Lite installation did *not* change the /etc/hosts `127.0.1.1       raspberrypi` line for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, even if you've changed the host name via `raspi-config`, the settings don't stick. To make it permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and change the line that says

```
127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

to

```
127.0.1.1       myhostname
```

assuming that *myhostname* is the name you want to use. Save, exit and reboot, and the message will go away.

Comment: Isn't the localhost IP 127.0.0.1?

Comment: [It's complicated …](https://serverfault.com/questions/363095/why-does-my-hostname-appear-with-the-address-127-0-1-1-rather-than-127-0-0-1-in). But this issue appears to be resolved in Raspbian.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thanks!